# React, Spring - serving two react applications from the spring backend

Tags: javascript, java, reactjs, spring, webpack

I've been working on a application and realized that certain users will only use one part of the react app and other users will only use the other part of the app. To simplify, lets say its a book ordering app, where the owner of the bookstore will only see the `Library Management` part of the app, and the customers will only see the `Book Ordering` part of the app. This two UI's will never interact with eachother, so it seeems to me like i should not be sending the customers the entire js bundle, since the customer does not need the javascript that makes the  `Library Management` part of the app work. I looked around at code splitting, but i wanted to try creating two react apps, and serving one to the bookstore owner, and one to the bookstore customers since it seems like i would have more control over how small or big the bundles can be.

**TLDR question:** **: In the index.html file, a `<script>` tag gets inserted that points towards `link=/static/someJsBundle.js`. How do i change that to point to something like: `<script link=my-folder/static/someJsBundle.js`.**

Long version of question:

Right now, i am still serving the the entire react app as one index html file and this is how i handle it:

1. I build the react app, and move the build folder (which contains the index.html and the js bundles) to the `/target/classes/public` folder of my backend module, where all my backend classes are.
2. I configure my backend to use a resolver and serve the `index.html` file:

```java
// configuration for resource handler

 registry.addResourceHandler("/url-for-ui-pages/**")
                .resourceChain(false)
                .addResolver(resolverThatReturnsTheIndexHtmlFile);

 registry.addResourceHandler("/js/**").addResourceLocations("classpath:/public");
 registry.addResourceHandler("/css/**").addResourceLocations("classpath:/public");
```

```java
public class ResolverThatReturnsTheIndexHtmlFile implements ResourceResolver {

    private Resource index = new ClassPathResource("/public/index.html");

    @Override
    public Resource resolveResource(
            HttpServletRequest request,
            String requestPath,
            List<? extends Resource> locations,
            ResourceResolverChain chain) {

        return index;
    }
```

This is all working perfectly, my index.html gets served and it fetches all the bundles it needs.

However, now moving to serving 2 react apps, my setup changed like this:

1. I now build both react apps, and put one of their build folders in `/target/classes/public/book-store-ordering` and the other one in `/target/classes/public/book-store-management`.
2. I updated my resource handler to use two resolver, one for each react app

```java
// configuration for resource handler

 registry.addResourceHandler("/url-for-book-store-management-pages/**")
                .resourceChain(false)
                .addResolver(resolverThatReturnsTheIndexHtmlFileForManagement);

 registry.addResourceHandler("/url-for-book-store-ordering-pages/**")
                .resourceChain(false)
                .addResolver(resolverThatReturnsTheIndexHtmlFileForOrdering);

 registry.addResourceHandler("/js/**").addResourceLocations("classpath:/public");
 registry.addResourceHandler("/css/**").addResourceLocations("classpath:/public");
```

3. I modified the resolver i had, to serve the management app:

```java
public class ResolverThatReturnsTheIndexHtmlFileForManagement implements ResourceResolver {

    private Resource index = new ClassPathResource("/public/book-store-management/index.html");

    @Override
    public Resource resolveResource(
            HttpServletRequest request,
            String requestPath,
            List<? extends Resource> locations,
            ResourceResolverChain chain) {

        return index;
    }
```

4. I created a new resolver to serve the other app:

```java
public class ResolverThatReturnsTheIndexHtmlFileForOrdering implements ResourceResolver {

    private Resource index = new ClassPathResource("/public/book-store-ordering/index.html");

    @Override
    public Resource resolveResource(
            HttpServletRequest request,
            String requestPath,
            List<? extends Resource> locations,
            ResourceResolverChain chain) {

        return index;
    }
```

Now, based on which url i enter, i **get served the correct index.html**, however the static files it needs, it look for them at `/static/someJsBundle.js`. I can see this in the `<script link=/static/someJsBundle.js` tag that gets inserted in the `index.html` file.

Obviosuly, this is a problem, since i need one of my apps to look for its static files at `/book-store-management/static/someJsBundle.js` and the ohter one at `/book-store-ordering/static/someJsBundle.js`. I can then configure my resolver to serve the right static files based on which url comes.

- **How do i do that? How do i configure which url will be inserted into the index.html file for looking up the static js files?**
- **I have also never done something like this and i might be doing it in a wrong or overly-complicated way. Is there a better way to doing what i want to do?**

Answer (score 0):

Issue was fixed by just adding a resource handler handling /static/** and adding both public/orders and public/management locations.

As for: In the index.html file, a  tag gets inserted that points towards `link=/static/someJsBundle.js`. How do i change that to point to something like: `<script link=my-folder/static/someJsBundle.js`.
The answer is adding a 'homepage' in your package.json.